Пагинация wordpress выдает 301 ошибку и не отрабатывает
<section>
  <div class="cards">
    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( array(
      'numberposts'  => -1, 
      'category_name' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'category_name_child', true), 
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => '3',
    ));

    if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
      while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :
        $wp_query->the_post();
  
    <figure class="card__post">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('adv_thumbnail'); ?>
      <figcaption class="">
        <h2 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"
           target="_blank"
           rel="noopener noreferrer">
           <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'btn_card_value', true); ?>&nbsp;&raquo; 
        </a>
      </figcaption>
    </figure>        

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 10px auto;">
    
      <?php 
      $args = array(
        'show_all'     => false, // показаны все страницы участвующие в пагинации
        'end_size'     => 1,     // количество страниц на концах
        'mid_size'     => 1,     // количество страниц вокруг текущей
        'prev_next'    => true,  // выводить ли боковые ссылки "предыдущая/следующая страница".
        'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
        'add_args'     => false, // Массив аргументов (переменных запроса), которые нужно добавить к ссылкам.
        'add_fragment' => '',     // Текст который добавиться ко всем ссылкам.
        'screen_reader_text' => __( 'Posts navigation' ),
        'class'        => 'pagination', // CSS класс, добавлено в 5.5.0.
      );
      
      the_posts_pagination( $args ); ?>

    </div>

    <?php else: ?>
        Записей нет.
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</section>   


может быть не ошибку, а код http-ответа?

Не за#буйте с вашей пагинацией!!!

Нужные мне посты мне выводятся. Сама пагинация тоже присутствует, она выводит нужное количество постов на страницу во вкладку и делит посты на правильное количество вкладок. Но при нажатии на любую кнопку пагинации запрос возвращает 301 ошибку и в результате возвращает на туже в кладку. Визуально это выглядит так что при нажатии на любую кнопку пагинации страница просто перезагружается и ничего не происходит, все остается как было до нажатия.

ответ ошибки:  "Не удалось загрузить данные ответа: Доступного контента нет, так как этот запрос был перенаправлен."

@AlexSem 301 код -- не ошибка

переадресация понимаю, но мне нужен другой результат. Чтобы при нажатии на пагинацию был переход на страницу с категорией а он её не находит и перенаправляет обратно. Хотя посты поделены пагинацией на вкладки и к каждой вкладке присвоена своя ссылка

@AlexSem Вы с статьей которую Вам предложили, ознакомились?

Так же это архивная, не архивная страница, где Вы это пытаетесь вывести и почему именно так?

Да я пытался править код в соответствии со статьей, но получал тот же результат. Это страница с карточками. Карточки созданы как записи в определенной рубрике. Страница типа post

Так это страница с "карточками" или single post? Если single post, то зачем переопределение $wp_query да и если не single post то тоже зачем? Почему нельзя воспользоваться WP_Query и paginate_links()?

Страница типа post той самой рубрики, которой принадлежат карточки. post-cards.php - название файла. Шаблон подцеплен к странице через админку

изменив код добился, чтобы при нажатии на пагинацию происходил переход на страницу с категориями page/2/ и тп. Переход происходит, но на странице ничего не меняется.
код:
    <?php  if (have_posts()) : query_posts(array(
          'category_name' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'category_name_child', true),
          'posts_per_page' => 3,
          'post_type' => 'post',
          'numberposts'  => -1,
       ) ); 
      while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>    
    <?php endwhile;
      php the_posts_pagination();
   php wp_reset_query(); ?>


А зачем пагинация в шаблоне записи?

На сайте 3 рубрики с услугами(у них шаблон обычной страницы - page и они созданы из админки), в каждой сделано от 2х до 4х подрубрик и они выведены постами на этих страницах.
А в каждой подрубрике, есть пару десятков карточек реализованных через записи. Нужно чтобы они выводились не все на странице, а по 3шт. Я могу их конечно засунуть в какой-нибудь слайдер, но хотелось бы реализовать через пагинацию и разобраться в ней.

У рубрик есть свой шаблон где все по умолчанию работает, нужно только изменить количество выводимых постов.

Если же для Вас все еще по каким-то причинам жива идея использования страницы в качестве рубрики, не нужно переопределять глобальный $wp_query или использовать query_posts(), используйте WP_Query и paginate_links(), потому что само собой это будет работать плохо, если это делать не так как следует.

Не помогает тот же результат :( Если проще говоря у меня есть запись она выводится на шаблоне типа post и вот в ней я пытаюсь вывести записи из другой рубрики. Они выводятся, но пагинация хоть и выводится, то вообще не срабатывает, то срабатывает переходит на страницы подкатегорий но информация на странице не меняется.

Разобрался, пагинацию нельзя использовать на страницах типа post, только на page
